# php logic issue: uploading file and changing name

Tags: php, image, upload

I am new to php and trying to figure out how to perform the following process: Using the below code to upload images submitted by users, I want to change the name of the file based on user session data, and if the newly named file already exists, then replace it with the current upload.

At the point where the following snippet is taken from is where I think this process should happen. However, instead of checking if the file exists, I want to just accept the file, rename it to something like ($_GET['session_name'] . "-avatar" . $extension), and if that file already exists in the uploads folder, then replace it with the current uploaded image. And finally, the file's extension shouldn't be a factor in determining a files existence, this way only one file per user will exist no matter the type of file.

```
// edit following to rename file, and if exists already, replace with current
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

Complete code below ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)):

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: You can use the `glob()` function to look for filenames matching a pattern. So remove the extension from the filename, and use `glob($basename.'.*')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$UserSessionData);
```

to rename the file to your user session data thingy.
Do the same with `if(file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) [...]`.

btw: You should use singlequotes (') in php, because doublequotes (") are parsed by php and therefore slower than singlequotes.

Comment: Thanks for this! but what about append the file extension to the custom name? fileName = $_SESSION['user_name'] . '-avatar' . $needFileExtension;

Comment: got it! $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])); 
 $avatar = $_SESSION['user_name'] . '-avatar' . '.' . $ext;

Answer (score 0):

To check that the file exists without looking at the extension your have two easy solutions :

- Create a directory per user and put the file in it, so you can iterate or count users files.
- Use a database